# C++ Vector of Class and sorting by filed

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, sorting, vector

Welcome,
i have class

```
Class test{
   string a;
   string b;
}
```

in main

```
vector<test> t;
```

and how sorting by filed a ? sorting ASC and DESC?
i don't have know idea how doing this soritng

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with custom comparators:

```
bool less_by_a(const test& lhs, const test& rhs)
{
  return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}
```

then

```
#include <algorithm>

...
std::sort(t.begin(), t.end(), less_by_a);
```

and similarly for the greater-than by `a` variant.

Answer (score 3):

There is standard algorithm std::sort in C++. It can accept a predicate that specifies the order of sorting.

So to sort the vector in the ascending order you can write

```
std::sort( t.begin(), t.end(), []( const test &t1, const test &t2 ) { return ( t1.a < t2.a ); } );
```

provided that data member a has the public access control (in your example it has private access control).

To sort the vector in the descending order you simply reverse the condition

```
std::sort( t.begin(), t.end(), []( const test &t1, const test &t2 ) { return ( t2.a < t1.a ); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use internal operator `<` for `class test` :

```
class test {
    //..
    string a;
    strint b;
    //...
    bool operator<(const test& t) const  
    {
        return a < t.a;
    }

   //..

};
```

Then,

`std::sort(t.begin(),t.end());`

Comment: I think it is much better to use a custom comparer, because this class does not seem to have an obvious default criterion for comparison (it could be `b` rather than `a`, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You may write an universal comparator like this:

```
template <typename T, typename S, template <typename> class L>
struct compare : public std::binary_function <const S &, const S &, bool> {
    compare (T typename S::* f) : f (f) { }

    bool operator () (const S & lhs, const S & rhs) const {
        return L <T> ().operator () (lhs.*f, rhs.*f);
    }

private:
    T typename S::* f;
};

template <template <typename> class L, typename T, typename S>
compare <T, S, L> make_compare (T typename S::* f) {
    return compare <T, S, L> (f);
}
```

And then use it:

```
std::sort (t.begin (), t.end (), make_compare <std::less> (& test::a));
```

But "test::a" field must be public.